# Get array from firebase and show data

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I have data downloaded from firebase in this form:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IokT2.png)
by this code:

```
function Question(props) {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  const route = useRoute();
  let quizDane;
  firebase.firestore()
  .collection('quizes')
  .doc(route.params.klucz)
  .onSnapshot(documentSnapshot => {
        console.log('Data: ', documentSnapshot.data());
        quizDane = documentSnapshot.data();
        console.log('description: ', quizDane);
      });
```

...
And I try to show dataon return:

```
<Text style={styles.pytanie}>
{
    {quizDane.description}
}   
</Text>
```

I get error: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'quizDane.description')
Problem is that react try show quizDane.description before download data and set quizDane variable.
How can I repair it and show correctly data from array?

Comment: You're going to have to use a react state hook to store the results of the asynchronous query for a future render, whenever it becomes available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way

```
// Add default state undefined of quizDane
const [quizDane, setQuizDane] = useState();


function Question(props) {
  ......
  .onSnapshot(documentSnapshot => {
        
        quizDane = documentSnapshot.data();
        setQuizDane(quizDane); // reset state here so will rerender again
   });
}
```

on `render`

```
<Text style={styles.pytanie}>{quizDane && quizDane.description ? quizDane.description : "Data Fetching..."}</Text>
```

Comment: How Can I get data quizDane.quest1[0].pytanie?

Comment: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'quizDane.quest1[0]')

Comment: This shows you are using it before it gets data. Share your code where are you using it

Comment: my code
 {quizDane && quizDane.quest1[0].pytanie ? quizDane.quest1[0].pytanie : "Data Fetching..."}

Comment: Try adding `{quizDane && quizDane.length > 0 && quizDane.quest1 && quizDane.quest1.length > 0 && quizDane.quest1[0].pytanie ? quizDane.quest1[0].pytanie : "Data Fetching..."}`

Comment: that's works: {quizDane && quizDane.quest1 && quizDane.quest1[0].pytanie ? quizDane.quest1[0].pytanie : "Data Fetching..."} Thanks <3